# Combine Form::text and error check into one?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In the blade view file, I have something like this:

```
  {{ Form::text('contact_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
    @if ($errors->has('contact_name')) 
        <div class="error-block">{{ $errors->first('contact_name') }}</div>
    @endif


    {{ Form::text('contact_email', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
    @if ($errors->has('contact_email')) 
        <div class="error-block">{{ $errors->first('contact_email') }}</div>
    @endif
```

When user press submit, it will check inputs validation in the controller. However, if there is an error with the validation, it will then redirect back to a form and populate it with error messages `{{ $errors->first() }}`

Is there a way to exclude `{{ $errors->first() }}` in the view file and still show error messages if validation failed? So combine `Form::text` and `$errors->has`into one function or something like that?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what exactly you want to do? It is not very clear

Comment: @TheShiftExchange I have updated a bit more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Form Macro](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#custom-macros) to do this

```
Form::macro('myText', function($field)
{
    $string = Form::text($field, null, ['class' => 'form-control']);
    if ($errors->has($field)) {
         $string .= $errors->first($field);
    }

    return $string;
});
```

Then in your view

```
{{ Form::myText('contact_email') }}
```